# How to sign out from Windows 11 in a Remote Desktop session?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I work for an ISV. We are not deploying Windows 11 to everyone's desksides/laptops any time soon, but we do need to check that our products work correctly on Windows 11. So we have some Windows 11 machines set up, and developers and testers access them via Remote Desktop.

The problem is that there's no obvious way to log out of Windows 11. The power button icon on the new Start Menu offers **Disconnect**, **Sleep**, **Shut down** and **Restart**, but no **Log out** or **Sign out**, as Windows 10 does. The only way I can log out at present is "shutdown /L" in the Command Prompt, and I'm pretty sure that's not what Microsoft intends to be used.

The situation is the same on x86-64 Windows 11 Enterprise and ARM64 Windows 11 Pro. On Windows 10, the Start Menu has an entry that shows the user name, and hovering over that shows the **Sign out** option. I can't find anything that corresponds to this on Windows 11.

I've searched the Windows 11 help, and tried a general web search, but not found anything. Suggestions?

Comment: I still use Win10, but does the default task manager on Win11 still come with a users menu and a logoff option?

Comment: Try the suggestions in this article:  https://www.lifewire.com/classic-start-menu-in-windows-11-5189891#:~:text=Restart%20your%20computer.,back%20in%20will%20also%20work.   I have two Windows 11 Pro machines (Production and Insider) and both offer Sign Out and it works.

Comment: It would be worth a short phone call.. hey - when I click disconnect, can you check it’s signed out? Unless it’s a multi-license server, the local Machine would present only a sign in option as soon as any remote user connected, making the point moot.

Comment: @MiG: Do you mean the CTRL-ALT-DEL menu? Sadly, one cannot get at that when working through two levels of Remote Desktop: Home machine to office, office to Windows 11 test machine.

Comment: @John: What version of Windows 11 are you on? I'm on 22000.434, and the article says the old-style Start Menu is specific to particular versions.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The Windows 11 machines are not on anyone's desk, but in a server room, and we're all working remotely.

Comment: I am on the most current version of Windows 11 and using the native menus (nothing extra).

Comment: @John: Version number, please? "ver" in the Command Prompt is an easy way to get it. There are so many Insider and other channels that an actual version number is best.

Comment: @JohnDallman try CTRL+SHIFT+ESC, this is the keyboard shortcut for the task manager. CTRL+ALT+DEL might get intercepted yeah, but maybe this one is sent through.

Comment: Version 22000.434

Comment: @MiG: CTRL-SHIFT-ESC only goes through one layer of Remote Desktop here. It may well matter if the RDs are full-screen.

Comment: silly workaround idea: pull up the on-screen keyboard on the last machine and try said shortcut?

Comment: Why is that in-between-machine there in the first place btw? I assume/hope this is not representative of your eventual production environment. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to set your test environment up so you won't need that?

Comment: Microsoft [says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sign-out-of-windows-346925bb-024c-cd86-7a53-9066242a9ed3):"To sign out of Windows 11, select Start. Select the Accounts icon (or picture), then select Sign out". Have you tried to *click* the user's icon/name?

Comment: @harrymc: Aha, that's it. I'm so used to the idea that pictures of the user are pointless wastes of screen space that I didn't try it. Turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft [says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sign-out-of-windows-346925bb-024c-cd86-7a53-9066242a9ed3):

> To sign out of Windows 11, select Start. Select the Accounts icon (or picture), then select Sign out".

Differently from Windows 10,
to logout in Windows 11 *click* the user's icon/name
and then click "Sign out" in the menu which appears.